# Slice list of lists without numpy

Tags: python, list, slice

In Python, how could I slice my list of lists and get a sub list of lists without numpy?

For example, get a list of lists from A[1][1] to A[2][2] and store it in B:

```
A = [[1,  2,  3,  4 ],
     [11, 12, 13, 14],
     [21, 22, 23, 24],
     [31, 32, 33, 34]]

B = [[12, 13],
     [22, 23]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can *slice* `A` and its sublists:

```
In [1]: A = [[1,  2,  3,  4 ],
   ...:      [11, 12, 13, 14],
   ...:      [21, 22, 23, 24],
   ...:      [31, 32, 33, 34]]

In [2]: B = [l[1:3] for l in A[1:3]]

In [3]: B
Out[3]: [[12, 13], [22, 23]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also perform nested list slicing using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function as:

```
B = map(lambda x: x[1:3], A[1:3])
# Value of B: [[12, 13], [22, 23]]
```

where `A` is the list mentioned in the question.